# Login to JIRA Rest API using Personal Access Token in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to login to Jira REST API using PAT (Personal Access Token) , able to that with username and password but not with with PAT.
Can anyone help with this.

Attached my code below.

```
def authString = "USERNAME :PASSWORD".getBytes().encodeBase64().toString()
def subtask = new URL("JIRA_URL" + jiraid).openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
subtask.setRequestMethod( "GET" )
subtask.setRequestProperty( "Authorization", "Basic " + authString )
subtask.doOutput = true
subtask.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
                                            
def result = subtask.getInputStream().getText()
```

With username and passwords authentication is working fine but failing with PAT.